# opencv in centos 6.5

Tags: c++, opencv, centos6

I have installed opencv recently . I am trying to do a bit if image processing using opencv and cuda. but I am getting an error like this

```
nvcc -o reference_hw1 reference_main.o student_func.o compare.o reference_calc.o -arch=sm_20 -Xcompiler -Wall -Xcompiler -Wextra -m64 -L /usr/lib  
reference_main.o: In function `preProcess(uchar4**, unsigned char**, uchar4**, unsigned char**, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
reference_main.cpp:(.text+0xc4): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
reference_main.cpp:(.text+0x1b7): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
reference_main.cpp:(.text+0x1cd): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
reference_main.cpp:(.text+0x1ea): undefined reference to `cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)'
reference_main.o: In function `postProcess(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned char*)':
reference_main.cpp:(.text+0x45a): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
reference_main.cpp:(.text+0x4a2): undefined reference to `cv::imwrite(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
reference_main.o: In function `generateReferenceImage(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
reference_main.cpp:(.text+0x5b2): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
reference_main.cpp:(.text+0x5d4): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
reference_main.cpp:(.text+0x5ee): undefined reference to `cv::imwrite(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
reference_main.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
reference_main.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD5Ev]+0x39): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
reference_main.o: In function `cv::Mat::operator=(cv::Mat const&)':
reference_main.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MataSERKS0_[cv::Mat::operator=(cv::Mat const&)]+0x111): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)'
reference_main.o: In function `cv::Mat::create(int, int, int)':
reference_main.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat6createEiii[cv::Mat::create(int, int, int)]+0x96): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::create(int, int const*, int)'
reference_main.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
reference_main.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[cv::Mat::release()]+0x47): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
compare.o: In function `compareImages(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, bool, double, double)':
compare.cpp:(.text+0x4e): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
compare.cpp:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
compare.cpp:(.text+0x8c): undefined reference to `cv::operator-(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&)'
compare.cpp:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to `cv::abs(cv::MatExpr const&)'
compare.cpp:(.text+0x15a): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::reshape(int, int) const'
compare.cpp:(.text+0x15f): undefined reference to `cv::noArray()'
compare.cpp:(.text+0x17b): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
compare.cpp:(.text+0x1a9): undefined reference to `cv::minMaxLoc(cv::_InputArray const&, double*, double*, cv::Point_<int>*, cv::Point_<int>*, cv::_InputArray const&)'
compare.cpp:(.text+0x20c): undefined reference to `cv::operator-(cv::Mat const&, cv::Scalar_<double> const&)'
compare.cpp:(.text+0x22d): undefined reference to `cv::operator*(cv::MatExpr const&, double)'
compare.cpp:(.text+0x2d2): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::reshape(int, int) const'
compare.cpp:(.text+0x33d): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
compare.cpp:(.text+0x375): undefined reference to `cv::imwrite(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [student] Error 1
```

I don't know why the error is like this. My Makefile is

```
NVCC= nvcc

###################################
# These are the default install   #
# locations on most linux distros #
###################################

OPENCV_LIBPATH=/usr/lib
OPENCV_INCLUDEPATH=/usr/local/include
OPENCV_TROUBLE= 


CUDA_INCLUDEPATH=/usr/local/cuda/include


NVCC_OPTS =  -arch=sm_20 -Xcompiler -Wall -Xcompiler -Wextra -m64

GCC_OPTS =  -Wall -Wextra -m64

student: reference_main.o student_func.o compare.o reference_calc.o Makefile
    $(NVCC) -o reference_hw1 reference_main.o student_func.o compare.o reference_calc.o $(NVCC_OPTS) -L $(OPENCV_LIBPATH)  $(OPENCV_TROUBLE)

reference_main.o: reference_main.cpp timer.h utils.h reference_calc.cpp compare.cpp reference_hw1.cpp
    g++ -c reference_main.cpp $(GCC_OPTS) -I $(OPENCV_INCLUDEPATH) -I $(CUDA_INCLUDEPATH) $(OPENCV_LIBPATH) $(OPENCV_TROUBLE)

student_func.o: student_func.cu utils.h
    nvcc -c student_func.cu $(NVCC_OPTS)

compare.o: compare.cpp compare.h
    g++ -c compare.cpp  -I $(CUDA_INCLUDEPATH) $(GCC_OPTS) -I $(OPENCV_INCLUDEPATH) $(OPENCV_LIBPATH) $(OPENCV_TROUBLE)

reference_calc.o: reference_calc.cpp reference_calc.h
    g++ -c reference_calc.cpp   -I $(CUDA_INCLUDEPATH) $(GCC_OPTS) -I $(OPENCV_INCLUDEPATH) $(OPENCV_LIBPATH) $(OPENCV_TROUBLE)

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.png hw
```

In the directory  of /usr/local/include

there are two folders opencv and opencv2 , so everything is fine according to the arrangements .

Now how to solve the problem ? 
yesterday whole day got used in solution for this problem.
Please anybody help me.. Thanks in advance...
I tried all the methods.....

Comment: Your makefile doesn't reference any actual openCV libraries that I can see.  So the linker is throwing a bunch of undefined reference errors for anything that should be resolved in an openCV library.

Comment: Thank you will test and let you know